# Cannot upgrade Eclipse from 2022-03 to 2022-06

Tags: updates, eclipse

I added the "latest" update site (`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`), 
clicked on `Help -> check for updates`, clicked on `Next >` twice but eclipse refuses to update itself.

Errors in the error log / view are:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2022-08-22 14:31:15.903
!MESSAGE An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.904
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.906
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,jakarta.transaction-api,1.3.3
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.908
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.inject,1.0.0.v20220405-0441
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.909
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.collections,3.2.2.v20220405-1659
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.911
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang,2.6.0.v20220406-2305
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.913
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.resolver,1.2.0.v20220401-1849
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.915
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.bouncycastle.bcpg,1.70.0.v20220507-1208
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.918
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.bouncycastle.bcprov,1.70.0.v20220507-1208
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.919
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.core,3.6.400.v20220317-1003
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.921
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.3.300.v20220408-0629
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.926
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.native,6.2.200.202204200013
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.927
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32,6.0.300.202204200013
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.929
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64,6.0.600.202206081808
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.933
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare,3.8.400.v20220420-1133
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.937
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare.core,3.7.0.v20220513-0551
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.938
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.commands,3.10.200.v20220512-0851
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.938
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem,1.9.400.v20220419-0658
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.940
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.jobs,3.13.0.v20220512-1935
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.942
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net,1.3.1200.v20220312-1450
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.943
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_64,1.1.600.v20220312-1450
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.944
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources,3.17.0.v20220517-0751
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.945
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime,3.25.0.v20220506-1157
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.945
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.core,3.19.100.v20220324-0630
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.947
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.ui,3.16.100.v20220526-0826
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.951
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchview,1.0.200.v20220308-0315
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.951
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,1.10.0.v20220430-0424
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.952
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.di,1.8.200.v20220512-1957
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.953
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier,0.16.300.v20220503-2248
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.954
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.services,2.3.200.v20220513-1235
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.955
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui,4.7.300.v20220420-0901
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.956
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt,0.14.500.v20220511-1639
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.957
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme,0.13.100.v20220310-1056
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.958
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.ide,3.16.100.v20220310-1350
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.959
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,2.2.100.v20220331-0744
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.959
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,0.15.500.v20220511-1638
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.959
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,0.16.500.v20220506-1520
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.960
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.core,3.1.6.202206011447
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.963
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.doc,3.1.6.202206011447
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.966
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.ui,3.1.6.202206011447
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.967
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.30.0.v20220426-0617
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.968
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.30.0.v20220313-0955
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.969
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.25.0.v20220325-0806
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.970
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.6.0.v20220516-1117
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.971
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.27.0.v20220426-0617
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.972
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.10.0.v20220502-0731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.973
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32,1.10.0.v20220502-0731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.974
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui,1.10.0.v20220502-0731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.974
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui,1.10.0.v20220502-0731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.974
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.css,1.10.0.v20220502-0731
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.975
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.common,4.24.0.20220609-1200
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.976
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.jee,4.24.0.20220609-1200
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.976
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.common,3.16.100.v20220315-2327
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.979
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox,1.2.200.v20220315-2155
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.982
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64,1.2.500.v20220509-0833
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.987
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,1.4.500.v20220420-1427
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.988
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core,2.9.100.v20220310-1733
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.989
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,2.5.300.v20220421-0708
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.990
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,2.7.400.v20220329-1456
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.991
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor,1.2.300.v20220420-1427
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.991
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata,2.6.200.v20220324-1313
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.992
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,1.4.100.v20220329-1456
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.995
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher,1.7.100.v20220420-1427
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.998
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse,1.4.100.v20220420-1427
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:15.999
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository,2.6.100.v20220422-1806
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.000
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools,2.3.100.v20220504-1755
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.001
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse,2.3.200.v20220503-2330
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.001
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives,1.4.400.v20220506-1821
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.002
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf,1.3.300.v20220512-1321
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.002
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,2.7.500.v20220423-1604
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.003
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport,1.3.300.v20220329-1456
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.003
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite,1.2.300.v20220420-1427
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.004
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.preferences,3.10.0.v20220503-1634
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.004
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.base,4.3.700.v20220607-0700
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.006
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.ui,4.4.0.v20220411-0938
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.007
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.webapp,3.10.700.v20220510-1941
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.007
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.18.1200.v20220607-0700
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.008
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.4.100.v20220318-0906
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.010
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.3.150.v20220318-0906
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.011
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.30.0.v20220524-1333
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.012
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.16.100.v20220513-2002
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.012
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.19.200.v20220430-1851
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.014
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.12.700.v20220513-0809
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.014
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.15.1400.v20220530-0646
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.015
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.14.100.v20220411-0722
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.016
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core,3.11.300.v20220317-1517
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.017
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit5.runtime,1.0.1500.v20220308-2347
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.018
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.19.600.v20220409-1932
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.018
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.26.100.v20220516-1138
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.019
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.http,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.020
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.io,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.020
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.jndi,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.020
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.plus,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.022
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.security,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.022
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.server,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.022
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.023
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.util,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.027
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.028
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.webapp,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.029
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.xml,10.0.9
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.029
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface,3.26.0.v20220513-0449
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.030
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.notifications,0.5.0.v20220401-0716
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.031
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.text,3.20.100.v20220516-0819
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.031
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.4.400.v202205260129
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.032
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet,1.2.401.v202204060243
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2022-08-22 14:31:16.033
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.navigator.ui,1.1.1000.v202204060258

[... many more similar message omitted]
```

Upgrading eclipse seems to be still a challenge.
**Who can help me out, how can I fix these (for me meaningless) errors?**

Thank you.

Comment: Try the [Eclipse Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: @harrymc can the eclipse installer do updates, too?

Comment: The description in the above link says "The easiest way to install **and update** your Eclipse Development Environment."

Comment: @harrymc didn't find a way to update my local eclipse (not installed with oomph/eclipse installer)

Comment: Have you enabled [Contact all update sites during install to find required software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages)?

Answer (score 0):

As your current installation was not installed with the installer and is
not upgradable, the only solution I can think of is to install
a fresh installation, starting from scratch and this time by using the
official installer.

You will find the installer in the
[Eclipse Installer website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).